# This code has no error but after closing my editor and re run it, it shows me type error length is not defined how can i solve it

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

this code is correct but when i close my editor and restart it and i use hyper terminal to run my server after running my server it shows length is not defined type error why is that i don't know how can i solve it please solve it for me i have tried it many times as possible but i am not able to solve it

//jshint esversion:6

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
// const date = require(__dirname + "/date.js");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"))

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/todolistDB", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: true })

const itemSchema = {
    name: String
}

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemSchema)

//default item collection starts
const item1 = new Item({
    name: "Welcome to our todolist"
})

const item2 = new Item({
    name: "Hit the checkbox to delete an item"
})

const item3 = new Item({
    name: "Hit the '+' to add an item"
})
//default item collection end

const defaultItems = [item1, item2, item3]

// inserting items to DB



//getting and posting items to the web starts from here
app.get("/", function (req, res) {

    Item.find({}, function (err, foundItems) {

        if (foundItems.length === 0) {
            Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    console.log("sucessfully saved default items");
                }
            })
            res.redirect("/")
        } else {
            res.render("list", { listTitle: "Today", newListItems: foundItems });
        }

    })
    // const day = date.getDate();



});

app.post("/", function (req, res) {

    const itemName = req.body.newItem;

    const item = new Item({
        name: itemName
    })
    item.save();
    res.redirect("/")
});

app.post("/delete", function (req, res) {
    const deletedItems = req.body.checkbox;
    Item.findByIdAndRemove(deletedItems, function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("sucess");
            res.redirect("/")
        }
    })
})

app.get("/about", function (req, res) {
    res.render("about");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: length is at line no. 47

Comment: Have you ever checked what `err` is returning? It would be very helpful if you could comment the line in the code where the exception occurs as well as detail everything that you have already tried.

Comment: error=>       events.js:353
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at C:\Users\shivam\Desktop\allWebsites\todolist-v2-starting-files\app.js:46:24
    at C:\Users\shivam\Desktop\allWebsites\todolist-v2-starting-files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:5074:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at C:\Users\shivam\Desktop\allWebsites\todolist-v2-starting-

Comment: i have specified length to array that is not a string i have done this many times i am a newbie

Comment: if you want my ejs code then i will send that to u

Comment: That error is indicating that `foundItems` is not define, which for `Item.find` means it didn't find anything. Instead of `if (foundItems.length === 0) {` you should be able to do `if (type of foundItems != 'undefined' && foundItems.length > 0){ ... found things ... } else { ... didn't find things ... }`